# How to change environment variable such as 'process.env.NODE_ENV' in client side using webpack?

Tags: node.js, webpack

I have a javascript client side that is built with webpack. It is using `stats.js` to monitor the frame rate. But I don't want to show the stats window in production mode. I have tried all of the following:

1. Use `DefinePlugin` of webpack:

   ```
   new webpack.DefinePlugin({
         'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development')
   }),
   ```
2. In my javascript file, I use a variable to detect if it is in
   development mode or production mode.

   ```
   const isDevelopment = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
   ```

   Then if `isDevelopment` is true, I use the stats dom.

   ```
   if (isDevelopment) {
       const Stats = require('stats.js');
       stats = new Stats();
       document.body.appendChild(stats.dom);
   }
   ```
3. Pack my client side in production mode:

   ```
   webpack -p --progress
   ```
4. Run the app in production mode (this is server side):

   ```
   NODE_ENV=production PORT=8899 node server.js
   ```

But these settings, which supposedly run my app in production mode, do not stop the client side from displaying a stats window on the browser. Any clue what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind. Fixed it by putting `NODE_ENV=production` in front of `webpack -p --progress`. Seems webpack doesn't change the environment variable by default when using the `-p` argument. see [Issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2537).

So now I run webpack bundler as the following:

```
NODE_ENV=production webpack -p --progress
```